# How to find $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sup A_{n}$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \inf A_{n}$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, analysis, limsup-and-liminf

Given following set $A_{n} = (-\infty, \frac{1}{n} + (-1)^n)$

I tried to do something like this:

Found a $\sup$ and $\inf$ of given set
$$\sup A_{n} = \frac{1}{n} + (-1)^n$$
$$\inf A_{n} = -\infty$$

and then found limits:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sup A_{n} = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n} + (-1)^n $$
so I cannot compute previous limit

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\inf A_{n} = -\infty$$

I feel I was wrong somewhere. Can somebody explain how should I do it or where I am wrong?

Comment: You're right, but you should add that $\{\sup A_n,\;n\in\mathbf N\}$ has two limit points, $1$ and $-1$, which are the limits of the subsequences of terms of even and odd rank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have that
$$
\sup A_n  = \left\{ \begin{gathered}
   - 1 + \frac{1}
{n}\,\,\,\,if\,\,\,n\,\,is\,\,\,odd \hfill \\
  1 + \frac{1}
{n}\,\,\,if\,\,\,n\,\,is\,\,\,even \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.
$$
therefore 
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \left( {\sup A_n } \right) = \left\{ \begin{gathered}
   - 1\,\,if\,\,\,n\,\,is\,\,\,odd \hfill \\
  1\,\,\,if\,\,\,n\,\,is\,\,\,even \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.
$$